# CheckListBox SelectedItems.Count doesn't always work

Tags: c#

I have a dialog that contains three CheckedListBoxes.

To make it easier for an end user, I have a "All" checkbox that will selected all the items in "it's" corresponding listbox.

[image]

That functionality works just fine.

Before returning control to the calling form I want to make sure the user has selected at least one item in the first two listcheckboxes.

The problem I'm having is with the validating code that I have when a user clicks on the Ok button.

If a user clicks on individual rows in one of the listcheckboxes, the return value from that listcheckbox **selecteditem.count** method is not zero, but when I set all the rows using the listcheckbox **SetItemChecked** method it's zero.

Here is the code that I wrote to select all the rows when a "all" checkbox is checked.

```
  // set all the items to be selected.
    private void chkAllFields_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool CheckState = chkAllFields.Checked;

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListFields.Items.Count; i++)
            checkedListFields.SetItemChecked(i, CheckState);


    }
```

and here is the code where I check to see that at least one row is selected.

```
// see if any fields have been selected.
        if (checkedListFields.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select at least one field to include", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;  // don't allow this form to close
        }
        else
```

Has anyone ever experienced this before, and if so, is there a way to get around this problem ?

I've added logic that uses the CheckListBox GetItemChecked method to see if any rows were selected. While this logic works if I manually select a row, the problem still remains when I try to programmatically select all the rows in my CheckListBox using the SetItemChecked method.

```
   // see if any of the rows in the passed items is checked
    private bool AtLeastOneItemsChecked(CheckedListBox ListBox)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListBox.GetItemChecked(i) == true)
                    return true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `SelectedItems` is not the checked items.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but please fix your spelling of "recipient"  before shipping your code =)

Comment: I thought my way of spelling it looks weird. Thanks Nikki.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely confusing [selected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Contrary to what you might expect, the SelectedItems and
>   SelectedIndices properties do not determine which items are checked;
>   they determine which items are highlighted.

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-determine-checked-items-in-the-windows-forms-checkedlistbox-control) show an example of how to check how many entries are checked:

```
// Determine if there are any items checked.  
if(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)  
{  
   // If so, loop through all checked items and print results.  
   string s = "";  
   for(int x = 0; x <= checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1 ; x++)  
   {  
      s = s + "Checked Item " + (x+1).ToString() + " = " + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[x].ToString() + "\n";  
   }  
   MessageBox.Show (s);  
}
```